# Completeness - Normal iid sample with the variance known

Tags: statistics

How to prove that the family of distributions for a normal iid sample with known variance is complete without using the result that this normal family is a member of the exponencial family?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $T= \bar X$ is complete sufficient for Normal distribution and $T \sim N\left(\mu ,\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)$

\begin{align} E(h(T)) &=0\\\implies \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)\times C \exp\left(-\frac{n}{2\sigma^2}(t-\mu)^2\right)&=0\\\implies \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)\times\exp(-\frac{nt^2}{2\sigma^2})\exp\left(\frac{\mu nt}{\sigma^2}\right)&=0\end{align}
This implies $h(t)=0 \forall t$
This shows the result.